# grails gorm : formatted number and date

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-orm

I want to make my webapps able to receive & display formatted number and formated date in form
for example: 
for number : 1,000,000.00 
for date : 02/12/2013 *i will use jquery datepicker

what is the best strategy for this ?

should I create a transient field for each numeric and date fields ?
for example:

```
class Person{
 Date dateOfBirth;
 BigDecimal salary;
 ......

 String dateOfBirthFormatted;
 String salaryFormatted;

 static transients = ['salaryFormatted','dateOfBirthFormatted'];
}
```

or should I handle the formatted number and date fields in the view (using javascript and processed before submitting the form) ?

Comment: I think the idea is to format the data where it's being displayed (e.g., the view), and leave it in its raw format internally rather than cluttering up the model with convenience methods.

Comment: Otoh, I have a static formatter in one of my domains, so what do I know? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [**`formatNumber`**](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html) and [**`formatDate`**](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) tags respectively for `salary` and `dateOfBirth` if plan is to only get the data formatted in the view layer.

As far as the view goes it would look like

```
<g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${dateOfBirth}"/>
<g:formatNumber number="${salary}" type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" />
```

where `dateOfBirth` and `salary` being part of the model for this view.

Comment: not this one. I want user able to input formatted text in <input type='text' name='dateOfBirth' value=''/>

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript,

```
//date
    $("#dateOfBirth").datepicker({
                changeMonth : true,
                changeYear : true,
                dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                yearRange : '1901:2999',

            });
//salary
    if(/^(?!0\.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$/.test($("#salaryFormatted").val())){
             return true;
    }
    else{
        $("#salaryFormatted").attr("oninvalid", "setCustomValidity('Please enter the salaryin proper format eg:(100.00,10,000.00)')");
            $("#salaryFormatted").prop('required', true);
            $("#salaryFormatted").val("");
            return false;
    }
```

In gsp,

```
<input type="text" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth"
    value="${formatDate(format:'dd/MM/yyyy', date: personInstance?.dateOfBirth)}" />


<g:textField name="salaryFormatted" id="salaryFormatted" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" value="${String.format("%,.2f", personInstance?.salaryFormatted)}" />
```

Use the above code . I think, it will help

Answer (score 0):

Would this function i wrote help, where `sep` is the type of seperator in the date format, and if none is entered then none is returned.

```
function getDate(sep) {
    if(typeof sep==='undefined')sep='';
    var date = new Date();
    return (date.getFullYear().toString()+sep+(date.getMonth()+1)+sep+date.getDate());
}
```